# Second tab is always a black screen

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` that has 2 items. Each of them points to a different `UINavigationController`, however both of them point to the same `UIViewController`. The first item is displayed correctly but the second on is not. What's happening.
No code is necessary for reproducing it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A view controller can't be in different navigation controllers at the same time. You need two scenes here. This is one reason why I don't like Storyboards.

Comment: Do you mean creating a new view controller with the same content?

Comment: No, you don't need two view controllers. You need two scenes with the same view controller set as class.